# Deal with PostgreSQL concurrency using Rails find_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, concurrency, transactions

For some reason this code can create duplicated games if different users run it at the same moment:

```
game = Game.find_or_create_by(
    status: Game::STATUS[:waiting],
    category_id: params[:category_id],
    private: 0
) do |g|
  is_new = true
  g.user = current_user
end
```

I can't figure out clearly what is the matter, but probably its about different Unicorn processes which use different database connections so transactions can run in parallel.

If so, I need the right way to avoid it, maybe I should use Rails transactions or Postgres locks, but I really need an example of using.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe your issue is in current_user, but first change find_or_create_by to create_by since is_new  is true.

Comment: Add and [index to the database](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#sec-the_caveat) to avaoid duplicate entries?

Comment: manu29.d, actually I can't use UNIQUE index on [status, category_id, private]:
because I only need unique record when its status is 0 (WAITING). For other statuses I can have records, duplicating those columns.

Comment: Hitham S. AlQadheeb, I didn't get what you mean. What is the issue with current_user and what is create_by? `is_new` is used in the following code, just to know that the record has just been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *can* happen in high concurrency levels.

According to [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by), these queries will run:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE status = 'waiting' AND ... LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO games (status, ...) VALUES ('waiting', ...);
```

The second only runs, when the first haven't returned a row.

It is possible, if two (or more) connections starts the first query within a few microseconds, that multiple processes will create multiple entries. To prevent that, you can use an [`ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) on that table, or use a custom [advisory lock](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html).

You can use some unique index too, to prevent multiple entries to be inserted into your database, but if it's used on its own, that will cause SQL exceptions in this situation.

**EDIT**:

`ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock can be acquired through the [`LOCK` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html).

Advisory lock can be acquired through using the [`pg_advisory_lock(id)` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html).

Both requires you to run arbitrary SQL commands.

---

Another way would be to use custom queries with:

1. insert only if it's not exists (& return with all fields)
2. select only if not inserted

Something, like:

```
INSERT INTO games (status, category_id, private)
     SELECT 'waiting', 2, 0
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
               FROM games
              WHERE status = 'waiting'
                AND category_id = 2
                AND private = 0
       )
  RETURNING *;

-- only select, when this not inserted anything

SELECT *
  FROM games
 WHERE status = 'waiting'
   AND category_id = 2
   AND private = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please provide a little example on how to implement those types of locks in my rails code? Wouldn't rails transactions be useful in my case?